# Complex numbers homography

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm struggling to show that if a homography $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ sends set $\{z:\Im(z)>0\}$ to itself, then $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc>0$
I will be thankful for clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : You can use the identity : $Im(z)=\frac {1}{2i}(z-\bar z)$ and apply it to $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove that $H$ sends real axis into itself $\iff$ the coefficients are real